# Deferred Objects Usage Issue jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, github, jquery-deferred

So I have two AJAX calls, one nested within another. The idea is to pull repo information (title, link, description) from a Github account with one url and then pull commit information for the last 10 commits of the selected repo, which is located at a different url.

Everything is technically displaying, but I need the repo info to display and then the commit info to display immediately after, alternating as such:

- Repo 1 info

  - Repo 1 Commit info
- Repo 2 info

  - Repo 2 Commit info
- Repo 3 info...

So on and so forth like that. I've been doing a lot of digging and have found a lot on deferred objects, but I have no idea how to implement them for my situation. There aren't any examples online that look in any way similar to what I'm trying to do.

Here's my code so far (the github username is taken out of the url for anonymity's sake):

main function

```
function main() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://api.github.com/orgs/user/repos',

    success: function(data, status){
      alert(data);
      display_content(data);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error){
      var err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      alert(err.Message);
    }
  });
}
```

repo info function

```
function display_content(_data){
  for (var i = 0; i < _data.length; i++) {
      $("#listing").append(
        "<h2>" +
          "<a href=\"" + _data[i].html_url + "\">" + _data[i].full_name + "</a></h2>" +
        "<p>" + _data[i].description + "</p><br />"
      );
      commits(_data[i].name);
    }
  }
}
```

commit info function

```
function commits(repo){
  $('#listing').find('h3').text("Latest Commits to user/" + repo);
  return $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://api.github.com/repos/user/' + repo + '/commits',

    success: function(commit_data, status){
      var len;

      if(commit_data.length < 10){
        len = commit_data.length;
      }else{
        len = 10;
      }

      //names of months to make date display prettier
      var m_names = new Array("January", "February", "March", 
                    "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", 
                    "October", "November", "December");

      for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
        //converting from ISO 8601 date format to my format
        var time = new Date(commit_data[i].commit.committer.date);
        var time_write = m_names[time.getMonth()] + " " + time.getDate() + ", " + time.getFullYear();

        $('#listing').append(
          "<h3> Latest Commits to user/" + repo + "</h3><br />" + 
          "<ul>" +
            "<li>" +
              "<div>" +
                "<img src=\"" + commit_data[i].author.avatar_url + "\"><br />" +
                "<a href=\"https://github.com/" + commit_data[i].author.login + "\"><br />" +
                  "<b>" + commit_data[i].author.login + "</b><br />" +
                "</a>" +
                "<b>" + time_write + "</b><br />" +
                "<i>SHA: " + commit_data[i].sha + "</i><br />" +
              "</div>" +
              "<a href=\"https://github.com/user/" + repo + "/commit/" + commit_data[i].sha + 
                "\" target=\"_blank\">" + commit_data[i].commit.message +
              "</a>" +
            "</li>" +
          "</ul>"
        );
      }
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error){
      var err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      alert(err.Message);
    }
  });
}
```

If anyone could help me with implementing deferred objects with this, or even provide a better solution, that would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Is your question how to achieve the alternating display in HTML?  Is that what your question is really about because promises don't seem to have anything to do with that.  Promises are one tool that can be used to help manage asynchronous operations.

Comment: Yes it is, sorry I thought they were related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this approach, all data is displayed as soon as it arrives. The asynchronism of `commits()` makes this slightly tricky as :

- the `commit_data` returns are guaranteed to arrive after *all* the `<h2>` headers have been written.
- the various `commit_data` returns will arrive back in some unknown order, not necessarily in the same order the requests were made.

So (as you know) simply appending the data to `#listing` when it arrives would not work.

However, the desired effect can be achieved by *pre-creating*, below each `<h3>`, a container for the commits data and making a reference to those containers available to the commits display function such that it knows where to put its data when it arrives (and has been formatted).

First, split `commits()` into the AJAX part and the display part. This isn't strictly necessary but will help you see the wood from the trees. You end up with four functions as follows :

- `main()`
- `display_contents()`
- `commits()`
- `display_commits()`

The worked up functions will all be quite simple. Something like this (shamelessly based in jFriend's `octokit` example) should do it :

```
function main() {
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://api.github.com/orgs/octokit/repos'
    }).then(display_content, function(xhr, status, error) {
        return JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    }).fail(function(err) {
        console.error(err);
    });
}
function display_content(data) {
    var promises = data.map(function(item, i) {
        var $container = $('<ul class="commits" />');
        $("#listing")
            .append("<h2><a href=\"" + item.html_url + "\">" + item.full_name + "</a></h2><div>" + item.description + "</div>") //reinsert HTML expression here
            .append( $('<h3/>').text("Latest Commits to user/" + item.name ) )
            .append($container);//placeholder for commits content that will arrive later.
        return commits(item.name).then(display_commits.bind($container), function(xhr, status, error) {
            return JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        });
    });
    return $.when.apply(null, promises);
}
function commits(repo) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://api.github.com/repos/octokit/' + repo + '/commits'
    }).then(function(commit_data) {
        return { repo:repo, commit_data:commit_data }
    });
}
function display_commits(obj) {
    var commit_data = obj.commit_data,
        repo = obj.repo,
        len = Math.min(commit_data.length, 10),
        m_names = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
        c, time, time_write;
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        c = commit_data[i];
        time = new Date(c.commit.committer.date);
        time_write = m_names[time.getMonth()] + " " + time.getDate() + ", " + time.getFullYear();
        //`this` is a pre-made placeholder
        this.append("<li><div><img class=\"repo\" src=\"" + c.author.avatar_url + "\"></div><div><a href=\"https://github.com/" + c.author.login + "\">" + c.author.login + "</a></div><div>" + time_write + "<div/><div>SHA: " + c.sha + "</div><a href=\"https://github.com/user/" + repo + "/commit/" + c.sha + "\" target=\"_blank\">" + c.commit.message + "</a></li>");
    }
    return null;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f06ntbdp/2/)**.

The critical bit is the creation (and appending to the DOM) of `$container`s in `display_content()`, and their binding to `display_commits()`, thus making each `$container` available as `this` to a bound instance of `display_commits()`.

Comment: So I'm a bit confused. I've implemented everything you have so far, but now nothing is displaying on the page.
In the .then() in the main function you aren't passing any data through the display_content function. Is that something that needs to be done?
Also when you reference the $('<div class="commits" />'), this isn't creating a new div in the html correct? So then how would $container be working?

Comment: (1) In the clause `$.ajax(...).then(display_content, ...)`, the success handler `display_content` will receive the parameters passed to it when the AJAX response is received - ie `data`, `textStatus`, `jqXHR`. It's easier to understand with an anonymous function - `$.ajax(...).then(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR), ...)`. (2) `$('<div class="commits" />')` creates a new, jQuery-wrapped DIV element, which is inserted into the DOM a couple of lines later with the clause `.append($container)`.

Comment: I can't explain why nothing is displaying - maybe there's some small error in there. I would need to play around with a working version hooked up to a backend.

Comment: OK, with (modified) HTML added back in, there's slightly more to it. I have edited above and added a link to a demo (with CSS to beautify). Add `/show` to the fiddle's url to view in full page mode.

Comment: The images and dates seem to indicate that the commits are inserted in the right places.

Comment: Thanks I got it all to work out! I stupidly wasn't adding a call to main() to run the whole thing.

Comment: @homeofmatt, don't feel too bad. Before I debugged the code, nothing appeared anyway :(

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a good way to do this is to fetch all the data and then when you have all the data, you can build all the HTML at once.  This also allows you to keep your functionality separate where you can get the data in one function and then format the data in another function.

Here's a way, using promises, to get the data.  I plugged in actual working URLs from the github documentation so I could test this in a jsFiddle:

```
function getRepoInfo(user) {
    var url = 'https://api.github.com/orgs/' + user + '/repos';
    return $.get(url).then(function(data) {
        // get data for all the names and return a promise when all requests are done
        return $.when.apply($, data.map(function(repo) {
            return $.get('https://api.github.com/repos/' + user + '/' + repo.name + '/commits').then(function(commit_data) {
                return {repo: repo, commits: commit_data};
            });
        }));
    });
}

getRepoInfo('octokit').then(function() {
    // put the arguments into an actual array
    var data = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    // data is an array of objects {repo: repoData, commits: [array of commit objects]}
    display_content(data);
});
```

At the moment, I haven't attempted to rewrite your display functions, because I'm assuming that once you have all the data available at once, you can work out how to create the HTML structure you want.

Working demo of `getRepoInfo()` that actually fetches the data: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/sy33sw0p/

---

If you've never used promises before, this will likely look a bit greek to you so I'll attempt to explain, but this is fairly advanced promise usage so I probably won't succeed in explaining it all.  Anyway here goes:

First off, a key concept in promises is that if you return a promise inside a `.then()` handler, then those promises become linked and the original promise will not be resolved until the new inner promise is also resolved.  I'm using that concept of chaining promises heavily in this solution.  Second off, `$.when()` returns a promise that is essentially a summary promise of all the promises you passed it.  So, if you have N async actions all running at once and you want to know when all of them are done and collect all the results at once, then `$.when()` can be really handy.  In this case, the code is going to get one master URL that gives us a bunch of other things to query about so logically, this is how it's going to flow:

```
Do First Query to get list of repositories
    When that finishes, fire off a new query for each repository 
    to get info about the repo
       When each of those finishes, grab data from the response and return it
    Return a new promise that is the combination of all the individual repo queries
    That new promise will be linked into the original promise and will 
    collate all the data from the individual repo queries
```

When first query's promise (and by definition all other linked promises) is resolved
   then, pass all the data to another function to build the desired DOM representation of the data.

Here's an explanation of some of the individual steps:

```
$.get(url)
```

Does the original ajax call that gets a list of repos and returns a promise that will be resolved when this ajax call and any other dependent promises are all done.

```
$.get(url).then(fn);
```

Set up a callback function to be called when that original ajax call is done and pass that callback function the results of that ajax call.

```
 return $.when.apply($, data.map(function(repo) {
```

This one is a bit complicated.  The operation that happens first is `data.map()`.  This iterates through all the repos from the original ajax call, calling a new function for each one.

That new function is this:

```
 return $.get('https://api.github.com/repos/octokit/' + repo.name + '/commits').then(function(commit_data)
```

which requests the commits for each repo.  When that request is done, it takes the data and formats it into an object of the form: `{repo: repo, commits: commit_data};` and returns it.  This becomes the resolved value of each promise that is created in the `data.map()` call and will ultimately be part of the returned data from the outermost promise.

Going back up to `return $.when.apply($, data.map(function(repo) {`, `data.map()` produces an array of promises because the callback passed to `.map()` returns a promise each time it is called.  We then use `$.when()` to create a new promise that is resolved when all the promises in the `data.map()` array of promises are done.  That promise becomes the return value for the `getRepoInfo()` function.

Comment: Even though I ended up going with Roamer-188s solution I want to thank you for your solution as well. I really appreciated how in-depth you were and your explanation of everything was very helpful!